# Dtach and Vim over Ssh: Reattach Session

Tags: ssh, terminal, nohup, dtach

I connected to my server:

```
$ ssh me@example.com
```

While in the server, I open a `dtach` session with `vim`:

```
$ dtach -c \tmp\my-dtach-session-pipe vim
```

Then my ssh session dies. I attempt to go back to my session:

```
$ ssh me@example.com
$ dtach -a \tmp\my-dtach-session-pipe
```

I do not get vim, but instead just a blinking cursor. I cannot do anything from there, not even <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>, I can only detach the `dtach` with <kbd>ctrl+\</kbd>.

How can I get my dtach session back properly? Or am I missing the idea of how dtach is supposed to behave?

N.B. I am well aware of the `tmux` and `screen` utilities.

Comment: 1. Why are you using backslash? 2. Why are you use dtatch instead of (arguably wider known and easier to use) screen or tmux? 3. Wouldn't it be better to open shell session inside the dtach session in which there would be vim session? Sometimes full-screen applications gets confused by changing screen size and suspend (<kbd>C-z</kbd>) and resume (`fg`) fix it.

Comment: I use `tmux`. I would like to learn `dtach` so that I can learn it and use it in combination with `dvtm`.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for adding the *dtach* tag. I would have if I had enough rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can prevent this by passing a [`WINCH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGWINCH) signal to `dtach`:

```
dtach -c /tmp/my-dtach-session-pipe -r winch vim
```

Or at reattachment:

```
dtach -a /tmp/my-dtach-session-pipe -r winch
```

Comment: I tried `dtach -a dtach-pipe -r winch` and that did not seem to re-attach my vim session, either, but if I use the `-r winch` option on creation (`-c`), it does work. Now the question is, if I forget to use `-r winch` can I get my `dtach` session back?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you did get what you want, but you need to redraw the screen? Try pressing <kbd>CTRL + L</kbd>.

Comment: Incidentally, how do I make `ctrl+L` look like a keyboard button?

Comment: <kbd> element will give you the cool button thing, but not on comments.

On another note, I had already tried `ctrl+L`, but it did not work, but you still get a +1 for a great suggestion.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping that was it ;-)